# List view really slow and laggy

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm loading around 500 rows of data into a `List`. It was okay when I had 10 rows but now that I have 500 it's extremely slow. Is there anything I can do to help it's performance?

```
        List {
            SegmentedControl(selection: $feedType) {
                ForEach(FeedType.allCases.identified(by: \.self)) { type in
                    Text(type.rawValue)
                }
            }

            ForEach(store.stories) { story in
                NavigationButton(destination: Text("")) {
                    StoryRow(story: story)
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Add some code example. We are not able to read your mind.

Comment: Show me your code, my hint is that you are not dequeuing the cell, but you are creating a new cell every time.

Comment: @AbuzarAmin he's using `SwiftUI` so there's no cell to dequeue

Comment: @Pancho Alright, I added my code.

Comment: Its a beta framework, and buggy as heck. Raise a bug with that issue. The devs will appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Yeah as @WarrenBurton suggested this is a beta framework and more than likely very buggy. Report the issue and see if the developers have something to say about it

Comment: Can't imagine the apple developers overlooked a case in which users will populate a list with more than 10 items :')

Comment: What if you add `.drawingGroup()` on the `ForEach`?

Comment: is it slow on live rendering mode or on the simulator ?

Comment: Off topic? Seriously? A List View is using table view cells at the background and it is strange why the cells do not get reused. Performance should be priority in Lists since they have dynamic amount of rows and it is not strange to have 500 rows.

Comment: What is in your StoryRow . Is it a heavy cell / lots of elements?

Comment: @WarrenBurton No, it just has two `Text` elements wrapped in a `VStack`

Comment: I doubt it’s a de-queuing issue as Apple engineers have mentioned that that was a hack for the days of the original iPhones to save memory and that it’s not as critical now. Have you tried poking at your app with Instruments to see what’s gobbling frames.

Comment: @WarrenBurton Any source?

Comment: @J.Doe sorry, no. Maybe a blog by someone I trust furbo.org ? Or maybe a WWDC session? . It kind of made sense in that unless your cell has a large dearchiving cost then just spin up a new cell and let the tableview release them as they go out of view. I’m guessing that SwiftUI lists are not UI/NS tableview backed and are maybe big slabs of CALayer which might experience performance issues for large sizes in the beta releases. The question while valid is effectively asking “why isn’t the beta version of this black box working”.  It can’t be answered (yet)

Comment: @WarrenBurton A List holds UITableViewCells (visual debugger tells me). I can not imagine a trusted source really said reusing cells is something that was used in the past and isn't needed today. Some lists can contains hundreds of elements with media. Try to load everything up once, instead of lazy loading, without having any lag.

Comment: @J.Doe You made me curious as to what I had read about dequeuing was correct. Ive written a related blog post here. https://github.com/warrenburton/DequeueOrNot . tldr 1. For frame rate - yes , dequeing is best but not mandatory . 2. Memory wise - meh . 3. SwiftUI is doing a lot of work to render lists. Hopefully it gets better.  Thanks for the poke :-)

Comment: @WarrenBurton Interesting project, thanks for sharing!! :)